# how can I skip the '\n' in this code

Tags: java

I have the next code, which opens a this file:

```
procedure TeTruena is
   PI : constant Float := 3.141592;
   MAX: constant Int := 30;

   type Array is array(1 .. MAX ) de
Int;
   type Matrix es array( 1 .. MAX, 1.. MAX )
of Int;
```

and i have to separate each one of the words of this file in tokens like:

procedure(one token), is(another token), etc..

and this code is supposed to do all of this:

```
public class Lexic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int car; 
          String nameFile,lexem;        
          Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in); 
          System.out.print("Give me the name of the file: "); 
          nameFile = t.nextLine(); 
          t.close(); 
          try 
          { 
             File file = new File(nombreArchivo); 
             RandomAccessFile af = new RandomAccessFile(file,"r"); 
             while((car = af.read()) != -1) 
             { 
                if(car != ' ' && car != '\n') 
                { 
                    lexem = Lexic.readFile(nameFile,af); 
                    System.out.print("["+lexem+"]");
                } 
             } 
             af.close(); 
          } 
          catch(IOException ex) 
          { 
             System.out.println("Can not open file"); 
          } 
    }

public static String readFile(String name,RandomAccessFile r)
    {
          int car; 
          char c; 
          long position; 
          String s = null; 
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
          try 
          { 
             position = r.getFilePointer(); 
             r.seek(position-1); 
             car = r.read(); 
             if(specialChar(car)) 
             { 
                c = (char)car; 
                sb.append(c); 
                s = sb.toString(); 
             } 
             else 
             { 
                 while((car != -1) && (car != ' ') && (car!= '\n') && (!specialChar(car))) 
                  {    
                       c = (char)car; 
                       sb.append(c); 
                       car = r.read(); 
                       s = sb.toString(); 
                  } 
                 if(esCaracterEspecial(car)) 
                 { 
                    position = r.getFilePointer(); 
                    r.seek(position-1); 
                 } 
             } 
          } 
          catch(IOException ex) 
          { 
             System.out.println("Can not open file"); 
          } 
          return s; 
    }

    public static boolean specialChar(int car){
        char character[] ={'+','-','*','/','%',';',',','{','}','(',')','=','<','>',':'};
        for(int i = 0;i < character.length;i++){
            if(car == character[i])
               return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

but the problem is that the code is not ignoring the '\n' and it prints:

[procedure] [TeTruena] [is
]

why is this??

Comment: Use a BufferedReader and readLine

Comment: Are you on Windows?  Make sure your character is not `\r`.  Text files on Windows have both `\r` and `\n` between each line, and if you are using a class meant for binary files, you have to worry about both.

Comment: `\n` is for Unix and Unix like systems. Use the System property `line.separator` to make it work platform independent.

Comment: @asgs Using `line.separator` would be hard to do without changing his entire algorithm, since he's trying to read one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected when the input file uses the Unix character return (\n).

I suspect you're using Windows input, so adjust this line:

```
while ((car != -1) && (car != ' ') && (car != '\n')  && (!specialChar(car))) {
```

to this:

```
while ((car != -1) && (car != ' ') && (car != '\n')  && (car != '\r') && (!specialChar(car))) {
```

And it'll work.